# Can OP27 Trim pins float?

Tags: operational-amplifier, trim

I'm putting together a circuit using an OP27. I was not sure if the the TRIM pins of the OpAmps are allowed to float if no triming is required.

**Would allowing the pins to float adversely affect the OpAmps operation?**

[image]

Comment: I take it the datasheet is silent on the topic?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Nothing that I've found but i'm also not sure where to look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at the functional block diagram:

[image]

And reading page 14 in the datasheet:

> The input offset voltage of the 
>   OP27
>   is trimmed at wafer level. 
>   However, if further adjustment of V
>   OS
>   is necessary, a 10 kΩ trim 
>   potentiometer can be used.

It appears that the OP27 can function with the trim pins unconnected, because they are not really floating.